# Set the stack size of a shared library

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries, stack-size

Is there a way (using gcc) to set the stack size of a shared library ?
I build a *.so* that contain a single function that uses a big buffer as local variable.
Something like that:

```
void foo ( void )
    {
    int table [1000000] ; // 4 millions bytes table !
    ...
    }
```

I added the option `-Wl,-z,stack-size=4100000` but it has no effet (not even an error message).
By the way, this lib is meant to be invoked from java code (using JNA).
Since I didn't find any post about this peculiar question, I'm afraid it's not possible...

Comment: did you try `-Wl,--stack,4100000`?

Comment: thanks tstanisl, but unfortunately I got a " /usr/bin/ld: unrecognized option '--stack' "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible - functions from shared library work in the context of thread which calls them and that thread will either be a main application thread (which started in `main`) or a thread created with Pthreads (which will have stack allocated at thread creation time in `pthread_create`).

`-Wl,-z,stack-size` flag is only applicable to applications, not libraries, and sets the size of main thread's stack.